# how to give permission for custom setting in permission set

Tags: customsetting, permission-sets

Here is the issue, In DE org a **managed package was created** and it contains custom settings in which the value is added based on user choice **(values are inserted)**. only issue is the user's profile is not system administrator **(let's say standard user)**- Standard user cannot create or edit the custom settings. How should one specify the permission to insert data and mean while

```
if (Schema.sObjectType.MF_Primary_Objects__c.fields.Custom_Objects__c.isCreateable()){
       mffObj.Custom_Objects__c = true;
       mff.customObjects = true;
   }
```

since stadard user does not have permission is not creatable if i Remove the if condition everything is fine **(but the security review fails )**

Comment: While creating custom_setting, What type of visibility is given fro that?

Comment: yeah its public

Comment: the thing is if I remove isCreateable if condition, it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Users with the "Standard User" profile can not write to Custom Settings objects. To do this you need to grant users the "`Customize Application`" permission and this in turn requires the View Setup Configuration permission.

> From Salesforce docs: To manage, create, edit, and delete custom
>   settings: Customize Application

[Add Custom Settings Data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cs_add_data.htm&type=5)

So if possible you can try to replace it with custom objects.